# Microsoft Chart control converts \n in file names to newline characters

Tags: .net, vb.net, newline, mschart

I am using a Microsoft Chart control (system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart) in a Windows forms application, vb.net 2008. I use folder paths for the x values in a pie chart. Chart control converts a name like `c:\newfolder` into `c:[newline]ewfolder`. I tried adding a slash, making it `c:\\newfolder`, but this only changes it to `c:\[newline]ewfolder`. Is there a workaround for this behavior?

some code:

```
Chart1.Titles.Clear() : Chart1.Titles.Add("Largest Folders in " & txPath.Text)
Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie
Chart1.Series(0)("PieLabelStyle") = "Inside"
Chart1.Series(0).YValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Double
Chart1.Series(0).XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String

For i = 0 To 9
  xVal(i) = Format(value(i) / 1000000, "#,0") & " mb  " & fPath(i)
  yVal(i) = value(i)
  Next i
```

Comment: I tried that too -- it made it c:\\\[newline]ewfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works

```
Chart1.Titles.Clear() : Chart1.Titles.Add("Largest Folders in " & txPath.Text.replace("\", "|")
```

or

```
For i = 0 To 9 
 xVal(i) = Format(value(i) / 1000000, "#,0") & " mb " & fPath(i).replace("\", "|") 
 yVal(i) = value(i) 
Next i
```

Maybe replacing with "/" will even integration with Windows Explorer via copy paste possible.

Comment: I suppose that's a compromise between / and \.